# vector representation matlab vs numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have to switch between MATLAB and NumPy (Python 3.x) . What always causes problems for me, is the way vectors are used in NumPy.  In MATLAB a vector is more or less nothing else than a 1xn or nx1 matrix. To provide an example:

```
b=np.array([0,2])
```

is a (2,) array and in fact it is not useful for any matrix operation because in that case I have to do something like `b.reshape(2,1)` before. At almost any time I have to reshape the vectors/arrays returned by functions. Can someone tell me why NumPy arrays are not treated like column or row vectors by default? And because I have got to do it so often … is reshape the best way to do it?

Comment: I usually use `b[:, None]` if I need a (n,1) array.  `numpy` usually treats a (n,) array as (1,n), that is it adds new dims at the start if needed.  Matlab expends dims at the other end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, Numpy's array-based-syntax is much more flexible and convenient than Matlab's linear-algebra-based syntax. In most cases, numpy code will be more clean and easy to write/follow. The only few exceptions arise when you are performing *simple* linear algebra operations where Matlab's syntax is *slightly* more efficient.

Note that you do not need to `reshape` numpy arrays in order to mimic matlab's operations in most cases. For example `A.dot(b)` or `A@b` (python 3) where `A` is a matrix (2-dimensional `numpy.array`) is essentially the same as `A*b` in Matlab. Give yourself some time to familiarize with numpy and you will see that it is Matlab that "forces" you to overuse/abuse the `reshape` function, not numpy.

Comment: I wish this was true but slicing is a nightmare to keep track of.

Comment: @percusse That's probably true. However, I believe this nightmare would be even worse in matlab! :)